# Replace one column in a line in a text file using Python

Tags: python, list, file

I have a text file and it has the following contents

```
    #                                       
    #   Keywords:                                   
    #                                                                           
    LiFePO4                                     
    end                                     
    name    Li5FeO4                                 
    cell                                        
        18.557309   18.316802   9.125725    90.047539   90.100646   90.060551 0 0 0 0 0 0           
    fractional  1                                   
    Li  core    0.06001     0.059408    0.849507    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li1 core    0.025416    0.339078    0.128746    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li2 core    0.02517     0.838929    0.130747    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li3 core    0.525498    0.339179    0.127632    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li4 core    0.524753    0.841333    0.129329    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li5 core    0.179907    0.158182    0.634012    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li6 core    0.180817    0.666028    0.628327    1   1   0   0   0   0
```

This is the input that I need to supply to a tool which used in some research application. Now I need to replace the `0` on the first line which starts with `Li` on the third column from the last. That is, there are four zeros towards the end in each of the lines starting with `Li`. I need to replace the second zero and so the file will have the the contents as follows:

```
    #                                       
    #   Keywords:                                   
    #                                                                           
    LiFePO4                                     
    end                                     
    name    Li5FeO4                                 
    cell                                        
        18.557309   18.316802   9.125725    90.047539   90.100646   90.060551 0 0 0 0 0 0           
    fractional  1                                   
    Li  core    0.06001     0.059408    0.849507    1   1   0   1   0   0
    Li1 core    0.025416    0.339078    0.128746    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li2 core    0.02517     0.838929    0.130747    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li3 core    0.525498    0.339179    0.127632    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li4 core    0.524753    0.841333    0.129329    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li5 core    0.179907    0.158182    0.634012    1   1   0   0   0   0
    Li6 core    0.180817    0.666028    0.628327    1   1   0   0   0   0
```

This has to be done a number of times for the zeros in various positions and I have the following code. There are some more operations that I am doing in the same code.

```
import os
import shutil
import time


def edit_file(column, next_column):
    # Processing x.gin file
    file_name = './' + column + '.gin'
    file_handler = open(file_name, 'r')
    print("Processing " + file_name + " file")
    contents = file_handler.readlines()
    find_line = contents[14]
    find_line_array = find_line.split('\t')

    print(find_line_array)

    # change values according to the file name
    if column == 'x':
        find_line_array[8] = 1
    elif column == 'y':
        print(contents)
        print(find_line_array)
        find_line_array[9] = 1
    elif column == 'z':
        find_line_array[10] = 1
    elif column == 'xy':
        find_line_array[8] = 1
        find_line_array[9] = 1
    elif column == 'yz':
        find_line_array[9] = 1
        find_line_array[10] = 1
    elif column == 'xz':
        find_line_array[8] = 1
        find_line_array[10] = 1

    formatted = '\t'.join(map(str, find_line_array))
    contents[14] = formatted
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        for item in contents:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)
    print("Formatting completed for " + file_name)

    print('Executing GULP command ----')

    gulp_command = 'gulp ' + column + '.gin > ' + column + '.gout'
    print(gulp_command)
    shutil.copy(file_name, next_column+'.gin')

    file_handler.close()
    os.system(gulp_command)

    while not os.path.exists('./Li.grs'):
        print('Waiting for output file')
        time.sleep(1)

    if os.path.isfile('./Li.grs'):
        print('renaming file')
        os.rename('./Li.grs', next_column+'.gin')
        os.rename('./Li.grs', column+'.grs')

    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Starting Execution')
    column_list = ['x', 'y', 'xy', 'yz', 'xz']
    print(column_list)
    for index, column in enumerate(column_list):
        if column != 'xz':
            edit_file(column, column_list[index + 1])
        else:
            edit_file(column, 'xz')
    print('Execution completed')
```

I am replacing it correctly and rewriting the file. But this file doesn't appears to be in correct format as it has additional new lines. Is it possible that I can rewrite the single line only and so that I can keep the file in exact same format.

Answer (score 1):

i created a function for that. try this

```
def replace(filename,row,column,value):
    columnspan = "     "
    data = open(filename).read().split("\n")
    for i in range(len(data)):
        data[i] = data[i].split(columnspan)
    data[row][column] = value
    write=""
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for x in range(len(data[i])):
            write+=(str(data[i][x])+columnspan)
        write += "\n"
    write.strip()
    file = open(filename,"w")
    file.write(write)
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex` to find and update text:

```
import re

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f1, open('output.txt', 'w') as f2:
    data = f1.read()
    match = re.findall('Li\s+\w+\s+\d+\.\d+\s+\d\.\d+\s+\d\.\d+\s+\d\s+\d\s+\d\s+\d', data)
    for m in match:
        data = data.replace(m, f'{m[:-1]}1')
    f2.write(data)
```

Output:

```
#
#   Keywords:
#
LiFePO4
end
name    Li5FeO4
cell
    18.557309   18.316802   9.125725    90.047539   90.100646   90.060551 0 0 0 0 0 0
fractional  1
Li  core    0.06001     0.059408    0.849507    1   1   0   1   0   0
Li1 core    0.025416    0.339078    0.128746    1   1   0   0   0   0
Li2 core    0.02517     0.838929    0.130747    1   1   0   0   0   0
Li3 core    0.525498    0.339179    0.127632    1   1   0   0   0   0
Li4 core    0.524753    0.841333    0.129329    1   1   0   0   0   0
Li5 core    0.179907    0.158182    0.634012    1   1   0   0   0   0
Li6 core    0.180817    0.666028    0.628327    1   1   0   0   0   0
```